# how to add value from row every time it reads

Tags: mysql, vb.net, increment

i want to show the added values of Amount column to the lblamount every time the reader reads it. but what happens is it only replaces the values rather that adding it.

```
MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        query = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE Service_Name ='" & txtURThirdMolar.Text & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If reader.Read Then
            Dim amnt As Integer
            amnt = reader.Item("Amount")
            lblAmount.Text = +amnt
        End If
        MySqlConn.Close()
```

Comment: add as mathematically adding two numbers or join two strings? we don't see any math operation in your code. Besides, you need to consider your variable's scopes!

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  `lblAmount.Text = +amnt` is adding a value to a string.

Comment: @Plutonix I wouldn't agree with that. I don't know much about VB but I guess `+=` would be an addition, not `=+`.

Comment: either way, the issue is one side is integer, the other is string

Comment: @Plutonix Sure, but even if both sides were integers, `x = +y` would simply set `x` to the value of `y`, prefixed with a positive (and thus useless) sign, wouldn't it?

Comment: sorry guys, I'm not that "geek" in programming so as Im expecting, it's a wrong code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace  `amnt = reader.Item("Amount")` with  `amnt = amnt + reader.Item("Amount")`.....you could also replace it with  `amnt += reader.Item("Amount")`, its your choice...

Comment: thanks! :) but it's still not working with reader. So I coded it in for each loop statement and it works perfectly :)